# Two divs dynamically fill viewport height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having trouble trying to style this set up. The `#container` should be exactly the `height` of the `viewport`, the `#caption` should `take as much height as it needs`, and the `img in #image` should `fill the remaining height` (while maintaining its aspect ratio). Never should the `#container` exceed the viewport `height`.

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="image">
    <img src="my-image.jpg" alt="my-image">
  </div>
  <div id="caption">
    <p>
      Some info about this image.<br>
      Sometimes this could be two lines.<br>
      Maybe even three.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's an example of how this would work dynamically:

[image]

Any suggestions? I've fiddled with flex and tables myself too but no avail, the page always ends up exceeding viewport `height`.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `flexbox` for that

and you may need some media queries.

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh
}
#caption {
  flex: 1;
  background: red
}
img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="image">
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/300/500" alt="my-image">
  </div>
  <div id="caption">
    <p>
      Some info about this image.
      <br>Sometimes this could be two lines.
      <br>Maybe even three.
      <br>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is closer, but the image now sits behind the caption. I need it to dynamically scale smaller to not interfere with the caption.

Comment: in my snippet the img never goes behind the caption, they are siblings

Comment: Should the image be automatically scaling to fill the rest of the height? It seems like 'img { display: block; margin: auto }' is not enough to accomplish this

Comment: thats for horizontally, I guess you can do that only if you have defined height in one of the containers

Comment: Ended up using a jquery solution. Thanks anyways.